# Calling a separation algorithm in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump

I'm trying to solve a model using Julia-JuMP. The following is the outline of the model that I created. Here, `z[i,j]` is a binary variable and `d[i,j]` is the cost for which `z[i,j]=1`.
My constraint creates an infinite number of constraint and hence I need to use a separation algorithm to solve it. 
First, I solve the model without any constraint, so the answer to all variables `z[i,j]` and `d[i,j]` are zero. 
Then, I'm including the separation algorithm (which is given inside the if condition). Even though I'm including `if z_value == 0`, z_values are not passing to it.
Am I missing something in the format of this model?

```
m = Model(solver=GurobiSolver())

@variable(m, z[N,N], Bin)
@variable(m, d[N,N]>=0)

@objective(m, Min, sum{ d[i,j]*z[i,j], i in N, j in N} )

z_value = getvalue(z)
d_value = getvalue(d)

if z_value == 0
    statement
elseif z_value == 1 
  statement
end

@constraint(m, sum{z[i,j], i in N, j in N}>=2)

solve(m)

println("Final solution: [ $(getvalue(z)), $(getvalue(d)) ]")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're multiplying z by d which both are variables, hence your model is non-linear,

Are the costs d[i,j] constant or really a variable of the problem ?
If so you need to use a non-linear solver

Comment: d[i,j]s are constants. So the model is a linear one.

Comment: then why is `d` declared a variable? You even described the role of `d` as a variable in your question: " so the answer to all variables z[i,j] and d[i,j] are zero."